# Running multiple spec flow cases fails

Tags: specflow

Currently we are running around 2000 spec flow test cases
When we run spec flow we get object reference error or actual count = 0 
This issue occurs for few test cases randomly
If we manually run that test case then it gets passed.
The exact root cause is not detected as it is intermitent

So in order to resolve the issue we kept retry so that if a test fails we run that test again

This issue did not occur again for some time. However now since the number of test cases have increased we are facing the similar issue again

One of the resolution is to increase retry count. However we would like to know exact root cause so that we can apply proper fix for this issue.

Comment: Any comments on this ?

Comment: What testrunner are you using? Have you tried running all your tests in debug mode so you can see where the exceptions are being thrown?

Comment: When we debug then error is not coming

Comment: We are using msbuild